# Hyperlink underline behaving strangely in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

We came across an issue with a particular web font (Helvetica Neue, Pan-European) that causes really strange rendering glitch in IE (9, 10, 11, but not 8). The hyperlink underline is being randomly extended down the visible page. These underlines are not CSS borders, but the underline added by the browser on any regular link. They cannot be manipulated in CSS and do not appear in the DOM. It's not happening in any other browser, and we've spotted the issue in both desktop and mobile versions of IE.

Example:

[image: IE font rendering craziness]

I suspect it's some strangeness with the web font itself, but that begs the question why all browsers except IE are happy to display links correctly.

I've not been able to fix it. As the font is required by design, I've had to remove link underlines via CSS `text-decoration:none`.

Has anyone else come across similar issues?

Comment: There's a little more detail (screenshots) here, too: http://sheru.co.uk/ie-webfont-link-underline/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Unfortunately that doesn't fix it either. Curiously, there are some places in the content where links are displayed correctly. Toggling the font-family in the dev tools can also make the issue disappear temporarily - which all suggests that something is triggering IEs engine it mispaint the page...